# Adding a \n newline symbol when using sprintf in PHP

Tags: php, newline, printf

I'm trying to export existing data from a MySQL database, into ruby commands I can run with `rake db:seed`.

Here's my code.

```
# Generate db:seed data for proveedores.
$proveedores = R::findAll('tbproveedores');
$proveedoresE = R::exportAll($proveedores);

foreach ($proveedoresE as &$p) {

    $line = 'BookSupplier.create(company: "%s", city: "%s", country: "%s", address: "%s", telephone: "%s", contact: "%s", email: "%s", website: "%s"\n';
    $exportedLine = sprintf($line, $p['empresa'], $p['ciudad'], $p['pais'], $p['direccion'], $p['telefono'], $p['personacontacto'], $p['email'], $p['website']);
    var_dump($exportedLine);
    fwrite($seeds, $exportedLine);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Notice the `\n` newline symbol at the end of the $line variable. I read online that that was all that is needed to use a newline.

The output of my code above is (*vertabim, a long line*):

```
BookSupplier.create(company: "Pearson", city: "Lima", country: "Peru", address: "Av. Limon", telephone: "4673535421", contact: "Javier", email: "", website: ""\nBookSupplier.create(company: "Project Management Institute - PMI", city: "Pennsylvania", country: "Estados Unidos", address: "Newtown Square, Pennsylvania", telephone: "1", contact: "Limberg Morales", email: "", website: "http://www.pmi.org/"\nBookSupplier.create(company: "UVirtual - Centro de Excelencia", city: "Santa Cruz", country: "Bolivia", address: "Av. Irala 585", telephone: "1", contact: "Limberg Morales", email: "", website: ""\nBookSupplier.create(company: "Ábaco de Rodolfo Depalma", city: "Buenos Aires", country: "Argentina", address: "Viamonte 1336, 4° (C1053 ACB) Buenos Aires", telephone: "5411-43711675", contact: "Limberg Morales", email: "", website: "http://www.abacoeditorial.com.ar/"\nBookSupplier.create(company: "Pablo Lledó - ProjectManagement", city: "Canadá", country: "Estados Unidos", address: "Victoria, BC, Canadá", telephone: "1", contact: "Limberg Morales", email: "", website: ""\n
```

I'd like each call to be in it's own line, following my newline insertion. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The newline symbol `\n` will only being interpreted when it is enclosed in **double** quotes: `"`. Like that:

```
$line  = '...............';
$line .= "\n";
```

You should also know about `PHP_EOL` It is a constant that contains the systems newline delimiter which is different on several operating systems. For example it will be `\n` on Linux but `\r\n` on Windows. The most portable code would look like:

```
$line  = '.....';
$line .= PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 17):

If you can't (or don't want to) switch to double quotes, you can insert a newline using the ASCII code like so:

```
> php
<?php printf('line one%cline two', 10);^D
line one
line two
>
```

The `%c` lets you insert any ASCII code and 10 is the code for a newline.

Comment: although a magic number (kindof), i preferre this solution

Comment: Or better `printf('line one%sline two', PHP_EOL);`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use double quoted strings, single quoted ones don't expand special character sequences. Check out [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) for more details on PHP strings.

Answer (score 2):

The special characters in strings only work when it is enclosed in double quotes ("). See the [PHP string documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for more information.

So either use double quotes, which is a lot of work as you use quite a few double quotes in your string as well. And escape all double quotes inside the string.

Or if you are lazy, concatenate the new line afterwards:

```
$line = '...';
$line .= "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Josh's answer, you could inject the newline from an interpolated string into printf using %s `printf('something%s', "\n")` which starts to make more sense in a more complex example - e.g. if the string template is stored in a language variable, or you are doing multiple replacements, or just have to stick with sprintf because your PHB mandates it.

In your case it would be

```
$line = 'BookSupplier.create(company: "%s", city: "%s", country: "%s", address: "%s", telephone: "%s", contact: "%s", email: "%s", website: "%s"%s';
$exportedLine = sprintf($line, $p['empresa'], $p['ciudad'], $p['pais'], $p['direccion'], $p['telefono'], $p['personacontacto'], $p['email'], $p['website'], "\n");
```

I've formatted an email header block thus:

```
$headers = sprintf(
    'From: %1$s%2$sReply-To: %1$s%2$sMIME-Version: 1.0%2$sContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1%2$s'
    , $EMAIL_FROM, "\r\n");
```

repeating the use of the `\r\n` using the `1$` parameter index syntax.

So `%2$s` becomes the new `\r\n`, not taking up any extra chars but is harder to read!

Answer (score 0):

```
$line = "BookSupplier.create(company: '%s', city: '%s', country: '%s', address: '%s', telephone: '%s', contact: '%s', email: '%s', website: '%s'\n";
```

Double quotes are mandatory for \n(or any other whitescpace char like \t) to work.

Comment: Your string syntax is incorrect (it is even visible due to the syntax highlighting of [so]). You need to escape the double quotes *inside* the string.

Comment: Was to fast.. Edited it. I presume he used the quotes just to mark out the data from the vars, so changed them to single quotes(Escaping the double quotes is another possibility).